# ¿Cómo puedo retornar una función que contendrá una lista de tipo anónimo de una consulta a la base de datos?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

Tengo que devolver información para un reporte, por lo que necesito una consulta que retorne los siguientes valores (cantidad de pedidos completados por mes y diferenciados por año):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuyo equivalente en SQL es el siguiente:

```
select year([Order].[Date]) as 'Año', month([Order].[Date]) as 'Mes', count(month([Order].[Date]))  as 'Cantidad'
from [Order].[Order] 
where [Order].OrderStateId = 6 
group by year([Order].[Date]), month([Order].[Date]) 
order by year([Order].[Date])
```

Y para lo cual tengo en mi capa de repositorio el siguiente método equivalente a lo mostrado arriba en `LINQ` (en donde momentáneamente puse `object` como retorno):

```
public async Task<object> GetOrderForReport(int from, int to)
{
    return await _order.Where(x => x.OrderStateId == (short)OrderState.State.Paid
    && x.Date.Year >= from && x.Date.Year <= to)
        .GroupBy(x => new { x.Date.Year, x.Date.Month })
        .Select(x => new { x.Key.Year, x.Key.Month, Quantity = x.Count() })
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

El cual será llamado desde mi capa de servicio. Mi problema es que no se que retornar y como castearlo para que el tipo anónimo sea una lista de elementos que una vez obtenida en mi capa de servicio, la pueda iterar. Lo que retorna ahora mismo es lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo castear lo que retorna a un tipo concreto para poder iterarlo luego desde donde pida la información? Ósea poder iterarlo desde donde lo llame como lo podría hacer en el método, sin tener que definir una clase concreta para hacerlo. Como si dijera que lo que retorna es `List<new { int Year, int Month, int Quantity }>`

Investigando, lo mejor que encontré fue [Este post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520892/how-to-return-value-with-anonymous-method) pero no logré que nada de lo mencionado allí funcionase (todavía no estoy muy familiarizado con los tipos anónimos).

Comment: Aunque los tipos anonimos son muy convenientes, si sabes que vas a devolver, porque no definis la clase y devolves una lista de ese tipo de clase? aca no hay nada dinamico...

Comment: Sabiendo eso, es una buena opción. Quería estar seguro que no había otra forma de lograr lo comentado, para no tener que definir clases cada vez que tuviera estos casos. Dicho eso, si entonces no se puede lograr, hace una respuesta así te la puedo marcar como tal (o elimino la pregunta si no vale la pena al final).

Comment: Lo mio es un comentario solamente.. pero IMHO si siempre sabes que vuelve, entonces tenes un modelo, y ese modelo no va a cambiar... Capaz alguien opina distinto o sabe como hacer lo que vos queres, que seguro se puede hacer con reflection y alguna otra cosa.. pero el tema es.. vale la pena?

Comment: Mi idea era si en lo posible podía trabajarlo como si la llamada a la base la hiciera desde el mismo método en la capa de servicio, el cual no es mi caso, pero es el de muchos cursos o ejemplos en donde hacen todo en el controlador. Muchas veces retorno toda una entidad por dos o tres campos que son los que realmente necesito, porque sino tendría que crearle la clase para lo que retornaría la función anónima y no creo que tampoco valga la pena crear clases en esos casos. Para el de este post, por ahora lo veo como la solución.

Comment: "uchas veces retorno toda una entidad por dos o tres campos que son los que realmente necesito, porque sino tendría que crearle la clase para lo que retornaría la función anónima y no creo que tampoco valga la pena crear clases en esos casos. " charlemos en el [chat] porque no vale la pena crear clases, para algo que es siempre igual....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dejare las dos soluciones. La primera es la que me interesaba saber en el caso de que se quiera evitar crear la clase por la razón que sea, y la segunda con la clase concreta.

### Clase anónima

---

```
    public async Task<List<(int Year, int Month, int Quantity)>> GetOrderForReport(int from, int to)
    {
        var elements = await _order.Where(x => x.OrderStateId == (short)OrderState.State.Paid
        && x.Date.Year >= from && x.Date.Year <= to)
            .GroupBy(x => new { x.Date.Year, x.Date.Month })
            .Select(x => new
            {
                x.Key.Year, 
                x.Key.Month,
                Quantity = x.Count()
            })
            .AsNoTracking()
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Year)
            .ToListAsync();

        List<(int Year, int Month, int Quantity)> list = new();

        elements.ForEach(x => list.Add(new() 
        { 
            Year = x.Year,
            Month = x.Month,
            Quantity = x.Quantity
        }));

        return list;
    }
```

### Clase concreta

---

```
public class OrderForReport
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Y en el método del repositorio:

```
    public async Task<List<OrderForReport>> GetOrderForReport(int from, int to)
    {
        return await _order.Where(x => x.OrderStateId == (short)OrderState.State.Paid
        && x.Date.Year >= from && x.Date.Year <= to)
            .GroupBy(x => new { x.Date.Year, x.Date.Month })
            .Select(x => new OrderForReport() 
            { 
                Year = x.Key.Year, 
                Month = x.Key.Month, 
                Quantity = x.Count() 
            })
            .AsNoTracking()
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Year)
            .ToListAsync();
    }
```

Comment: No veo haya un costo grandísimo crear una clase, que funge como DTO, y además contribuye a la legibilidad y mejor comprensión del código. Personalmente, creo que es mejor tener una clase más en el ensamblado, que tener que hacer malabares para poder retornar un tipo anónimo. Si en realidad quieres evitar traer los otros campos, entonces, puedes utilizar [GraphQL](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-dotnet)

Comment: @Arriel De esa forma ya traigo los campos que me interesan (ver la foto de la variable local en donde indica tres campos), el problema (como lo mencione en la pregunta) es que pido la información en mi capa de repositorio pero la trabajo en la de servicio que es la que mapea lo que pido al DTO que retornare, por lo que el tipo anónimo lo puedo trabajar en el repositorio, pero no se puede retornar una lista de este a la capa de servicio para trabajarla de la misma manera. Creo que di con la solución, la estaré compartiendo dentro de no mucho (y es legible como en el caso de la clase concreta).